# How do I migrate my current deployment methodology to one using Docker?

Tags: python, git, fabric, docker

This is going to be a bit of along question, so be forewarned.

**The short version:**

Our current deployment system uses Fabric and Git to deploy a Python web application and supporting parts. The system works well but after spending 2 weeks working to extend it I realised I was essentially trying to re-invenˆt the Docker wheel. I thus decided to look at re-working things to use Docker. However, I'm having a bit of trouble working out how and where to mesh Docker into the current workflow.

**The long version:**

I'm currently working on an web application that consists of a Apache, Django back-end, Flask front-end, ElasticSearch deployment and PostgreSQL database. The back-end and front-end are exposed to the outside world via Apache and communicate with each other via said exposure.

Deployment makes use of Fabric and Git. Git is used to shuttle the changes around while Fabric manages all the tasks involved in configuring and managing the deployment environment.

The current system works well enough for basic usage. However, as we add more developers testing different branches is becoming more tricky. This is because each deployment environment (Currently there are 2, a staging server and a production server) is only able to server one instance of the whole application. Another difficulty comes in ensuring each developer has the correct setup to run the application correctly.

I spent two weeks working on improving the Fabric aspect of our deployment with some success. Unfortunately, the success opened up a can of worms in that I quickly realised it would lead to a whole lot of added development simply to replicate what Docker already does. As a result I decided to step back and thing about how to integrate Docker. I'm having some trouble working out how, though.

**Goals:**

Keep deployments as relatively simple as they are now: At the moment deploying 
basically just causes the deployment env to fetch the latest changes, backup the database, apply the changes, ensure the application config is correct and then restart any necessary services.

Make it easy to test branches: It would be great if I could tell the testers, etc that to test branch A they just need to browser to A.x.y.z and branch B can be found at B.x.y.z. The work I did with Fabric managed this for one component (The frontend) but it was while working on the Fabric file for the other components that I realised things were in danger of becoming a horrible mess.

Allow developers to develop in an environment as close to the deploymeny env without forcing them to run a mirror image of the deployment env: Deployment envs are great for deploying but not everyone wants to run Ubuntu on their dev box, for a variety of reasons. Docker seems to have a lot of potential with regards to replicating the deployment env locally without actually doing so.

**The Question part:**

The area I'm having trouble with is deciding what should be done with Fabric, Docker and Git.

Should I deploy Docker whole images including the application or use Docker to simply encapsulate the deployment env and then mount the application into the Docker image?

Or should I essentially try to replicate the current process within a Docker image?

Or should I come up with some new process the primarily makes use of Docker and reduces the amount of Fabric and Git involved?

Unfortunately it seems that there are many potential methods and I'm really not sure which one is recommended and which one as a bad idea.

Can anyone recommend a deployment methodology that will allow me achieve my goals without running into major problems?

Comment: Is your goal to "deploy" things for testing by an individual developer, or to deploy things such that they are generally accessible? I think there will be different solutions for these two situations.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Git, each developer is working on a specific branch right?
Generate a docker image for each branch(after a push for example). You can use fabric scripts to generate/deploy the docker image.

Also introduce http://boot2docker.io/ to your developers. :)